# Display Child View and Subscribe to its event on ReactiveUI

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am very confuse what is better approach to display child view and subscribe to its event on ReactiveUI WPF, so far I have 2 implementation that somehow works for my case:

**Implementation 1:**

```
public class ChildWindowView
{
    public event EventHandler<Exception> Error;
    public event EventHandler<bool> Closed;

    internal void ShowSomeChild()
    {
        var vm = new SomeChildViewModel();
        var view = new SomeChildView { DataContext = vm };

        ChildWindowManager.Instance.Show(view, "Child Title");

        Observable.FromEventPattern<Exception>
        (h => vm.Error += h, h => vm.Error -= h)
            .Subscribe(p => Error?.Invoke(p.Sender, p.EventArgs));

        Observable.FromEventPattern<bool>
        (h => vm.Close += h, h => vm.Close -= h)
            .Subscribe(p => Close?.Invoke(p.Sender, p.EventArgs));
    }

    internal void ShowOtherChild() { /* Code committed */}

    internal void ShowAnotherChild() { /* Code committed */}
}
```

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    private readonly ChildWindowView child = new ChildWindowView();

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        // this commmand executed several times during runtime
        ShowSomeChild = ReactiveCommand.Create(() => child.ShowSomeChild());

        // this commmand executed several times during runtime
        ShowOtherChild = ReactiveCommand.Create(() => child.ShowOtherChild());

        // this commmand executed several times during runtime
        ShowAnotherChild = ReactiveCommand.Create(() => child.ShowAnotherChild());

        // handle child view error message
        Observable.FromEventPattern<Exception>
        (h => child.Error += h, h => child.Error -= h)
            .Subscribe(e => /* Error Handling */);

        // do something when child closed
        Observable.FromEventPattern<bool>
        (h => child.Close += h, h => child.Close -= h)
            .Subscribe(e => /* Do Something */);
    }
}
```

As you see, on the first implementation `ChildWindowView` subscribe to an event on the `ChildViewModel` before invoking his own Event, this event then subscribed by `MainViewModel`.

The advantage in this implementation is `MainViewModel` only need to subscribe to child event once for any child, although `ChildWindowView` will subscribe to `ChildViewModel` every time `ShowSomeChild()` is called.

**Implementation 2:**

```
public class ChildWindowView
{
    public event EventHandler<Exception> Error;
    public event EventHandler<bool> Closed;

    internal void ShowSomeChild(SomeChildViewModel vm)
    {
        var view = new SomeChildView { DataContext = vm };
        ChildWindowManager.Instance.Show(view, "Child Title");
    }

    internal void ShowOtherChild(OtherChildViewModel vm) 
    {
        var view = new OtherChildView { DataContext = vm };
        ChildWindowManager.Instance.Show(view, "Child Title");
    }

    internal void ShowAnotherChild(AnotherChildViewModel vm)
    {
        var view = new AnotherChildView { DataContext = vm };
        ChildWindowManager.Instance.Show(view, "Child Title");
    }
}
```

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    private readonly ChildWindowView child = new ChildWindowView();

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        // this commmand executed several times during runtime
        ShowSomeChild = ReactiveCommand.Create(() => 
        {
            var vm = new SomeChildViewModel();

            // handle child view error message
            Observable.FromEventPattern<Exception>
            (h => vm.Error += h, h => vm.Error -= h)
                .Subscribe(e => /* Error Handling */);

            // do something when child closed
            Observable.FromEventPattern<bool>
            (h => vm.Close += h, h => vm.Close -= h)
                .Subscribe(e => /* Do Something */);

            child.ShowSomeChild(vm)
        });

        // this commmand executed several times during runtime
        ShowOtherChild = ReactiveCommand.Create(() => 
        {
            var vm = new OtherChildViewModel();

            // handle child view error message
            Observable.FromEventPattern<Exception>
            (h => vm.Error += h, h => vm.Error -= h)
                .Subscribe(e => /* Error Handling */);

            // do something when child closed
            Observable.FromEventPattern<bool>
            (h => vm.Close += h, h => vm.Close -= h)
                .Subscribe(e => /* Do Something */);

            child.ShowOtherChild(vm)
        });

        // this commmand executed several times during runtime
        ShowAnotherChild = ReactiveCommand.Create(() => 
        {
            var vm = new AnotherChildViewModel();

            // handle child view error message
            Observable.FromEventPattern<Exception>
            (h => vm.Error += h, h => vm.Error -= h)
                .Subscribe(e => /* Error Handling */);

            // do something when child closed
            Observable.FromEventPattern<bool>
            (h => vm.Close += h, h => vm.Close -= h)
                .Subscribe(e => /* Do Something */);

            child.ShowAnotherChild(vm)
        });
    }
}
```

On the second implementation, I move child vm creation and event subscribtion to MainViewModel, but I lose central subscribtion that can handle all close event from any child.

And here is the `ChildWindowManager` that used to display child view on both implementation

```
public class ChildWindowManager : ReactiveObject
{
    public static ChildWindowManager Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }
    private static readonly Lazy<ChildWindowManager> lazy =
        new Lazy<ChildWindowManager>(() => new ChildWindowManager());

    [Reactive] public string Title { get; set; }
    [Reactive] public bool IsOpen { get; set; }
    [Reactive] public FrameworkElement XmlContent { get; set; }

    ChildWindowManager ()
    {
        XmlContent = null;
    }

    public void Show(FrameworkElement content, string title)
    {
        XmlContent = content;
        Title = title;
        IsOpen = true;
    }

    public async void Close()
    {
        IsOpen = false;
        XmlContent = null;
    }
}
```

Or maybe someone have better solutions.